# Changing sprintf value according to value in a row

Tags: php, mysql, int, printf

My problem is this

I have a database that stores int value in row "status" that I want to represent certain order status:

0 = submitted

1 = delivered etc.

What I want to achieve is displaying certain text like in the example above instead of int value

My code for displaying whole list is

```
require 'database_connection.php';
$select_orders = "SELECT username, status, product1_num, product2_num FROM orders";

$result = mysql_query($select_orders);

<ol class="order_list">
        <?php while ($order = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                 
            $order_row = sprintf("<li class='single_order %s'>
                <ul>
                    <li class='username'>%s</li>
                    <li class='status'>%s</li>
                    <li class='product'>%s</li>
                    <li class='product'>%s</li>
                </ul>
            </li>", 
            $order['status'], $order['username'], $order['status'], $order['product2_num'], $order['product1_num']);
                echo $order_row;
            }
        ?>
</ol>
```

I tried using if statement inside sprintf but with no success.

Does anyone has any idea how to change displayed code here from

```
<li class="status">3</li>
```

to

```
<li class="status">Delivered</li>
```

?

Comment: Why donot you do the if statement out side of sprintf using another variable. Like $dummy = $order['status'] and then use it for the sprintf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array:

```
$status = array('Submitted', 'Delivered', ...);
```

Then use `$status[$order['status']]` when you're displaying it.

You can also do it in the SQL:

```
SELECT username,
    CASE status
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Submitted'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Delivered'
        ...
    END AS status,
    ...
```

Comment: Nice Answer , donot need extra if's as i suggested